# mt4 indicator count day

Tags: unicode, indicator, mt4

I need to use "Count Day" code for indicator.
It does work fine, but this indicator keeps previous day object till I restart MT4.

What is wrong below code?

```
if(day >= drowDays) {
break;}
```

Also you can see chart screenshot link.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not providing sufficient information to your problem :'(
With the limited info, what I can say is that you need to delete the graphical objects created for previous day.

Assuming your indicator will plot the latest line, then you MIGHT (again, this is a guess as there is not enough information of your code) be able to achieve it with the `ObjectsDeleteAll()` function at the start of your `OnCalculate()`. Obviously, this is not efficient, but is something you can think about.